# How is this a countable subset of the real numbers?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given functions $f$ and $g$ with domain $A$, the images $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ are each countable subsets of the real numbers.

If the function $h$ is such that for all $a$ in $A$

$h(a) = f(a) + g(a)$,

then how is it proven that the image $h(A)$ is also a countable subset of the real numbers?

First of all I know that for a set to be countable it must be both injective and surjective with some subset of the natural numbers (thus creating a bijection). Second, I understand that that a set can be either countably finite or countably infinite. This is for all intents and purposes the extent of my knowledge of countability, and I’d like to be able to apply it towards a proof if possible and if not then I’d at least like to relate the logic of a proof to such ideas.

I began a proof by considering the Image $h(A)$ and the possible existence of a subset of the natural numbers of which a bijection could be made. But a proof by contradiction seems like the wrong path (although briefly attempted). And a direct proof has proven to be too complicated of a line of reasoning for me to grapple with on my own. Perhaps my approaches are too simple? Or are there additional concepts I should know before attempting such a problem? Maybe the solution is simpler than I’m making it out to be? Anything would be appreciated.

(If helpful to know, this topic relates to my study of probability theory and discrete random variables.)

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ is countable?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes I do, particularly I know of a proof involving f:NxN->N such that f(a, b) = (2^a)(3^b). Since every natural number can be represented as a unique product of primes, it follows that the function would be an injection.

Comment: Well, note that $h(A) = \{f(a)+g(a)|a\in A\}\subset \{f(a) + g(b)|a,b\in A\}$.  And not that $k:f(A)\times g(A)\to \{f(a)+g(b)|a,b\in A\}$ via $k(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha+\beta$ (where $\alpha = f(a)$ for some $a\in A$ and $\beta = g(b)$ for some $b\in A$) is surjective.  You must have some theorems about if a surjection from a countable set to a set X exist then X is countable, and that a subset of a countable set is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $h(A)\subseteq T(f(A)\times g(A))$ where $T:\mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $T(x,y)=x+y$.  First chelck that $f(A)\times g(A)$ is countable and then conclude that $h(A)$ is countbale.